# Blueprints not aligned?

Tags: modeling

I just started out with blender and I want to model a car with blueprints, the thing is, the blueprints don't match up to each other.
I used the cube to make sure they match up, but when I started tracing, they don't match up at all

[image: Side view]

[image]

[image]

Whenever I try to fix them, the other side gets messed up.

Comment: This could be a discrepancy with the images opposed to your modelling.

Comment: or maybe you need to change the size of some of your background pictures so that they match? If necessary you can move the background image (X and Y factors), change its size (Size factor), rotate it (Rotation)...

Answer (score 1):

it is first necessary to check whether the images are compatible with each other.
Are the same places in the same direction in all the pictures?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they are